# Function is not conformal if derivative vanishes

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in $z_0$ and $f’$ have isolated zero here. I need to show that $f$ is not conformal in $z_0$.
I know examples of functions with vanishing derivatives, like $z\mapsto z^2$ which doubles the angles at the origin, but I’m not quite sure how to show that for a general function.